# Is it safe to remove items from reversed list?

Tags: python

I guess [it is a common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating) that it's unsafe to remove elements from the list while iterating over it. The typical solution is to make a copy of a list. What I've found that using `reversed(list)` does work too. And my question - is it really safe?

`reversed` seems to be just an iterator too (since I can't retrieve individual elements from it), so it doesn't copy the list and probably just accessing the original list's elements under the hood. So it's still not safe?

I'm talking about the case similar to the one below - it seems to work fine.

PS Not sure if it's the best example since `for item in my_list` doesn't introduce any errors too.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for item in reversed(my_list):
    if item % 2 == 0:
        my_list.remove(item)

# [1, 3, 5], no errors
print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens to work OK in your code, but it's not safe in general. See this example:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for i in reversed(l):
...     if 2 in l: 
...         l.remove(2)
...     print(i)
... 
3
3
1
```

Notice that it processes `3` twice.

In python 3, many built-in functions that iterate over sequences are lazy; they don't return a new list, they process elements of the original sequence as needed when they're called. You can tell these functions by printing the return value; `reverse()` returns something like

```
<list_reverseiterator object at 0x139117ca0>
```

As a result, they're often sensitive to changes in the original sequence while you're using them. Unless the documentation specifically says it's OK to modify the sequence, you should not assume any particular result.

Comment: so it's not safe only when you delete some other element besides the one you're currently iterating over?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the conditions are. It depends entirely on how the reverse iterator is implemented.

Comment: I don't think the interaction is explicitly defined by the language, so even if it works in some version of python you can't depend on it in the future.

Comment: Keep in mind that `reversed(l)` does not return a new list; it returns an object that keeps a reference to the original list, and whose `__next__` method looks up values in that list to produce the reversed iteration.

Comment: @chepner I think the OP realizes that, since they contrast this with making a copy.

Comment: @FamousSnake It's a dice roll. Your Python version might work if you delete *other* elements, mine might work if you delete only the current element, and someone else's might only work on a rainy Tuesday afternoon. It's not going to be consistent, so it's best just to avoid the behavior entirely.

Comment: @silvio-mayolo is there some example when it'll definitely break?

Comment: @FamousSnake Theoretically an implementation could make a copy of the list internally so that it never breaks.

Comment: @FamousSnake I'm curious: Do you realize that your example code does delete some other element besides the one you're currently iterating over, if there are duplicate even numbers? Anyway, at least in CPython it's highly unlikely to get changed, it hasn't in a long time, there's probably no good reason to change it, and they're very reluctant to change behavior that likely some people rely on.

Comment: @Barmar Making a copy sounds just wrong. It's supposed to be an iterator over the existing list. And if during the iteration I don't remove something but  merely *overwrite* an element not yet reached, that should really be reflected in the iteration.

Comment: @KellyBundy I didn't think that any implementation would actually do it. But since the interaction isn't specified, anything is possible.

Comment: @FamousSnake Btw, [fun](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3G3Mr43Myi0sUbBWijXTMdQx1LHSMgBhKx3JxpeUXKWSWpOYqZOYpFKWWpRYVp6ZoQHVpWnEpAAGUp1eUmptflqoBUq2JIpFYUJCalwKV4CooyswrgRsBcQjUPTB3AQA) code using that removal of duplicates for "grouping" (bringing equal values together).